# REST API: Use the same verb and resource for 2 different operations

Tags: rest, api

For REST APIs, can we use the same HTTP verb on the same resource to get 2 different operations? If so, how do we proceed?

For example, I send 2 requests `GET /user`, but for the first one I want to retrieve all the users and in the second I only want the first user.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add filters in the query string.

Comment: @spectras In my example I could do a route for `GET /user/1` to solve my problem, but I didn't want to come up with a too complicated example.